# Functional component renders four times - why not twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I came across this simple React functional component, which renders four times, while I would expect it to render once initially, execute the useEffect which updates the state and therefore render again. Instead the console sends 4 log outputs, indicating that it renders four times. Any idea why and any resources on the basic lifecycle of react functional components?

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => setJobs(["test"]), []);

  console.log("APP", jobs);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>{jobs}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-tree-t120d?file=/src/App.js:149-191

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not an artifact. In `index.js` they wrap the `<App/>` in `<React.StrictMode>`. That is what causes it.

Comment: I understand @T.J.Crowder, that's a great example of why all code is relevant, I will add it to the question, in case someone else stumbles onto the same thing

Comment: @AliNasserzadeh - I already did that for you. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's because of the react-production version that you are using from the CDN, the production version won't run the strict mode for performance reasons

Comment: @AliNasserzadeh - Yeah, I figured it out and fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because in your codesandbox you use `<React.StrictMode>` to wrap your `<App />`.

The docs specifically state (https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> Class component `constructor`, **`render`**, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> ....